# Is it safe to just put "\n" instead of "[\r\n]" when writing a JavaScript Regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, line-breaks, carriage-return, linefeed

**Update: my original test involving copy/pasting from a text file into the browser was flawed. I created a new test in JavaScript which verified that carriage return \r is in fact being matched.**

The following code logs `['\r', '\r', '\r']` to the console, which verifies that the `\r` is being matched:

```
<script>
    const CarriageReturn = String.fromCharCode(13); // char code for carriage return is 13
    const str = CarriageReturn + CarriageReturn + CarriageReturn;
    const matches = str.match(/\r/g);
    console.log(matches); // this will output ['\r', '\r', '\r']
</script>
```

---

### Original Question

The common method suggested by numerous StackOverflow answers and articles across the internet to match a line break in regular expressions is to use the ubiquitous token `[\r\n]`. It is supposedly to ensure compatibility with Windows systems, since Windows uses the carriage return `\r` and line feed `\n` together to make a new line, as opposed to just the line feed `\n` for UNIX based operating system such as Linux or Mac.

I'm beginning to think JavaScript ignores this distinction and just treats every line break as `\n`.

Today, I did an experiment where I created a text file with 10 carriage returns, opened up the text file, then copy/pasted the carriage returns into the regular expression tester at https://regex101.com.

When I tested all those carriage returns against the simple regular expression `\r`, **nothing matched**. However, using the alternative `\n` matched all 10 carriage returns.

So my question is, based on my experiment, is it safe to just write `\n` instead of `[\r\n]` when matching line breaks in JavaScript?

Comment: depends where you get the data. I bet the browser converted \r\n to \n when pasting.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew user253751's comment turned out to be the reason why the carriage returns (`\r`) weren't being matched. I posted an answer but can't accept it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

No, do not replace `[\r\n]` with `\n`.

Line ends at http://regex101.com are only `\n` and that is why you had no match with `\r`.

In real texts, both carriage return and line feed characters might need matching.

Besides, the dot does not match `\r` in JavaScript regex.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript treats newlines as `\n`, that's why it matched all when you tested it. `\r\n` is windows style of representing new lines while Unix based systems uses `\n`. If you are not sure, you can use this regex: `/\r?\n/`

Answer (score -1):

After doing a different test, it appears JavaScript **does** make a distinction between `\r` and `\n`, but not in all cases. Here are the exceptions:

1. If you generate a carriage return string in JavaScript using `String.fromCharCode(13)`, and try to match it with pattern `\r`, the pattern will match successfully.
2. If you type a line break with your keyboard directly into a `<textarea>` in your browser, it is interpreted by JavaScript as just `\n`. There will be no matches for `\r`.
3. If you copy/paste text containing carriage returns (`\r`) from a text file into a `<textarea>` in your browser, your browser will convert all the sequences of `\r\n` into just `\n`. So, it will appear as if JavaScript is ignoring the `\r`s in your text, but it's only because your browser removed them in the process of pasting it into the `<textarea>`.

I updated my original question with the test I ran to confirm that the `\r` token is matched when generated with `String.fromCharCode(13)`.